# How to Copy Text From One Multiple Input To Another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have two multiple input fields as shown below.

```
<input name='mark[]'/><input name='remark[]'/><br/>
<input name='mark[]'/><input name='remark[]'/><br/>
<input name='mark[]'/><input name='remark[]'/><br/>
```

Now when I input some value in the first `mark[]` then I want to copy it to the first `remark[]`. How to do this using jQuery or script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `input` event and find next `div` with `$(this).next("input[name='remark[]']")`

```js
$("input[name='mark[]']").on('input', function() {
  $(this).next("input[name='remark[]']").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='mark[]'/><input name='remark[]'/><br/>
<input name='mark[]'/><input name='remark[]'/><br/>
<input name='mark[]'/><input name='remark[]'/><br/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi @Habeeb for select you can use `change` event